# Determine if the series is convergent or divergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series is $\sum\dfrac{\left|\sin nx\right|} {n^2 }$
I used the comparison test in which I used the fact that $a_n=\dfrac{\left|\sin nx\right|} {n^2} \le\dfrac{n\left|\sin x\right|} {n^2}$. Since, $0\le\left|\sin x\right| \le1$, $a_n=\dfrac{\left|\sin nx\right|} {n^2} \le\dfrac{n\left|\sin x\right|} {n^2} \le\dfrac{1} {n^2} =b_n$. 
Because $\sum\dfrac {1} {n^2} $ is convergent, $a_n$ is convergent by comparison test. I want to know if it is correct or not.

Comment: The approach is correct, but you do not need to compare $\sin(nx)$ and $n\sin(x)$, you can use $|\sin(nx)|\le1$ immediately We do NOT have $$n|sin(x)|/n^2\le 1/n^2$$

Comment: How do you conclude that $\dfrac {n\left|\sin x\right|}{n^2} \le \dfrac 1 {n^2} \text{?}$ You just need to use $\left|\sin(nx)\right| \le 1$ so that $$ \frac{\left|\sin x\right|}{n^2} \le \frac 1 {n^2}. $$

Comment: @MichaelHardy It makes no difference at the end, but you forgot the $n$ in $|sin(nx)|$ in the last line.

Comment: @Peter : Quite right. Let's try again: $\dfrac{\left|\sin(nx)\right|} {n^2} \le \dfrac 1 {n^2}. \qquad$

Comment: In MathJax as in LaTeX, if you write (\dfrac 1 2 + \dfrac 3 4) you see $(\dfrac 1 2 + \dfrac 3 4),$ but if you write \left( \dfrac 1 2 + \dfrac 3 4\right) you see $\left( \dfrac 1 2 + \dfrac 3 4 \right)$ Around here we sometimes see people writing \left( x \right) where  (x) will do: $(x).$ But in this case \left| and \right| are needed to get the right spacing even though they're not needed to get the right size. Notice the conspicuous difference between$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$  \frac{n|\sin x|}{n^2} and \frac{n\left|\sin x\righ|}{n^2}: $$ \begin{align} & \frac{n|\sin x|}{n^2} \\  \\ & \frac{n\left|\sin x\right|}{n^2} \end{align} $$

Answer (score 2):

Why don't $$a_n=\frac{\left|\sin nx\right|}{n^2} \le \frac{1}{n^2}$$?

---

Your argument is incorrect, in fact

$$a_n=\frac{\left|\sin nx\right|}{n^2} \le \frac{n\left|\sin x\right|}{n^2}\le \frac{1}{n}$$

but $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{n}$ diverges so we **can not** conclude that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n$ converges